# Xcode 4.6 suddenly giving SIGABRT error

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios-simulator, sigabrt

I've been trying to make an application, upto this point it was working correctly, loading two different views and stuff, but as soon as I tried creating a separate UI for 4 inch devices it started giving the 'SIGABRT' error while launching.
I've tried reverting back, restarting, clearing Simulator, and shit but nothing works.
Even the backup that was working perfectly earlier has failed to launch…
❕[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJWI2.jpg)

LOG Snippet:

```
"*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "ViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set.'  
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1f65012 0x181de7e 0x1f64deb 0x8428c8 0x842dc8 0x842ff8 0x843232 0x7923d5 0x79276f 0x792905 0x79b917 0x262b 0x75f157 0x75f747 0x76094b 0x771cb5 0x772beb 0x764698 0x219edf9 0x219ead0 0x1edabf5 0x1eda962 0x1f0bbb6 0x1f0af44 0x1f0ae1b 0x76017a 0x761ffc 0x2332 0x2265)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb) "
```

What can be wrong?
[The View is connected to the File`s owner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEmFn.jpg)

Comment: Can you show/add the code where you load ViewController?

Answer (score 1):

Debuger says, that you must connect your root view in code with view in .xib
Go to the your view controller's .xib file and click right button of mouse in its view and connect your view with files owner:
[image]

Comment: sorry, I din`t understand

Comment: Is it a root view controller of your app?